# iOS: Get Facebook Access Token with Auto-Login

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I'm using Parse and Facebook for account management in my app. Whenever the user logs in through the facebook button, my code works perfectly because facebook sdk automatically generates a new access token. However, if I use an autologin code which checks whether user has already approved of the app, I have no access token and can't access facebook data for that user. I don't know how to request an access token for a user who has already agreed to use my app.

Loading data:

```
- (void)_loadData :(BOOL)updateData
{
    NSLog(@"entered _loadData");
    NSMutableDictionary* userInfoParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [userInfoParams setValue:@"id,name,email,gender" forKey:@"fields"];

    if([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Expiration date of token: %@", [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] expirationDate]);
    }
    else NSLog(@"No access token");


    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:userInfoParams];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection* connection, id result, NSError* error)
     {
         if(!error)
         {
             ...
         }
      }
}
```

Auto-login system:

```
 (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([PFUser currentUser] || [PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Yes");
        [self _loadData:YES];
        [self transitionToLoginSegue:(id)self];
    }
    else NSLog(@"No");
}
```

Also, the access tokens I receive when user clicks through the log in button last for 4 weeks, so if there was a way to manually assign an access token then I could do that, however `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` is not assignable so I can't do that either.

Comment: Do you mean one time login. for example if the user successfully logged in first time, then it should not ask for login?

Comment: Please store bool value yes when you are successfully logged in first time, then check that bool valye everytime, if it is yes please go to next page else show the login screen.

Comment: The problem is that I can't access persons data such as his friends if I don't receive the access token first. and the only way to receive it that I know of at this point is to force the user to constantly go and approve of the app through Facebook

Comment: Sorry for asking again and again . I done this before thats y asking, Did you call this function( - (IBAction)loginWithFacebook:(id)sender) to get the user friends data?   i will update the code below in Answer. Please ask any question u have.

Comment: I just realised I coppied the wrong code here in auto-login system. What you saw before was what happens when user clicks on login with facebook button. This code in `viewDidAppear` is what makes the auto-login work, however doesn't give me the access token.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code below,

```
 if ([self check_network])
      {

      START_LOAD;
      FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
      [login
       logInWithReadPermissions:  @[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"]
       fromViewController:self
       handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                   STOP_LOAD;
                   NSLog(@"Process error");
                   NSLog(@"%@",error);
                   TOAST_FOR_TRY_AGAIN;
                   /*
                   UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Try Again"
                                                                 message:nil
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
                   [alert show];
                    */
             } else if (result.isCancelled)
             {
                    STOP_LOAD;
                   NSLog(@"Cancelled");
             } else
             {
                   NSLog(@"Logged in");
                   NSLog(@"Result=%@",result);

                   [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,picture,email"}]
                    startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                    {
                          NSLog(@"Facebook result=%@",result);
                         if (!error)
                             {
                                [NSUSER setObject:result forKey:@"user_info"];
                                [NSUSER setObject:[result objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"skip_name"];
                                [NSUSER synchronize];

                                API_CALL_ALLOC(ls_apicall);
                                [ls_apicall Login: STRING([result objectForKey:@"id"])];

                          } else {
                                 STOP_LOAD;
                                NSLog(@"An error occurred getting friends: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          }
                    }];
             }
       }];
      }
      else
      {
            TOAST(TOAST_NETWORK_ERROR);
      }
```

Comment: When I use the `FBSDKLoginManager` the app permission request screen for user opens up automatically after app launch so it doesn't solve anything as I want to bypass it.